# How to make Vert.x return a 404 response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vert.x, openapi

I'm learning about Vert.x and created this simple function

```
public Maybe<UserPasswordCheckResponse> checkPassword(OperationRequest ctx) {
    String userId = ctx.getHeaders().get("userId");

    Maybe<User> getUser = UserRepository.getUserById(userId)
            .subscribeOn(RxHelper.scheduler(Vertx.currentContext().owner()));

    return getUser.map(result -> {
        UserPasswordCheckResponse userResponse = new UserPasswordCheckResponse();
        userResponse.setPassword(result.getPasswordFake());
        return userResponse;
    });
}
```

How do I make the returned response 404 when the user is not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `UserPasswordCheckResponse` extend `io.vertx.ext.web.api.OperationResponse`?

Then you can use the `setStatusCode` method.